How to extract JSON array in PieCloudDB
I am new to JSON, in my PieCloudDB Database there is a json column as follows(example data):
{"A001": ["123","124","125"],"A002": ["234","235","236"]}

Now I want to output the result like this:



my_key
my_value




A001
123


A001
124


A001
125


A002
234


A002
235


A002
236



I tried this:
SELECT 
  json_object_keys(attributes) AS my_key, 
  attributes ->>json_object_keys(attributes) AS my_value 
FROM 
  my_table;

But I got the result which is not what I expected:



my_key
my_value




A001
["123","124","125"]


A002
["234","235","236"]




I found functions that meets my requirements:
In PieCloudDB Database, I can use json_array_elements() to
split the elements in an array into rows and use json_each_text() to split key-value pairs into rows. Finally use trim() to remove double quotes.
SELECT
  my_key,
  trim(BOTH '"' FROM element::text) AS my_value
FROM
  my_table,
  json_each_text(attributes) AS key_value(my_key, my_value)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  json_array_elements(key_value.my_value::json) AS element;

